# How to define disjunctive normal form and conjunctive normal form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

The question is here:

(1) Obtain the disjunctive normal form of $(p\to q)\to(q\to p)$

(2) Obtain the conjunctive normal form of $(p\to q)\to(q\to p)$

I obtain the form $\lnot q\lor p$. Is it a disjunctive normal form or a conjunctive normal form? If consider it as the "or" of two propositions, it should be a disjunctive normal form. But if consider it as the "and" of $\lnot q\lor p$ and True, I guess it can also be a conjunctive normal form?

Did I misunderstand anything? And how to reach the answer of the other form?